# DotNetNuke SMTP not working Register new User

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dnn9

I am using DNN version 9, we setup SMTP and its working on testing SMTP while we are adding new user and check "send and mail to email to new user" is not working

[image]

I also Set User Registration to Private but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Setting registration to private will prevent new users from registering.

If the SMTP Test Message is being sent, the most likely culprit is that your SMTP server is refusing to send or relay to outside addresses.

Problems in sending to the SMTP server should generate items in the Admin log.

If the problem is actually in the SMTP Server, you'll need to find someone who can look at it's logs.  In the last few weeks, a company was having trouble sending some mails using SendGrid.  The problem was that SendGrid was configured to not send emails outside of a narrow address range.  Fixing the configuration at SendGrid fixed the problem.